# How to re-run only failed scenarios with cypress-repeat?

Tags: cypress

I have a .feature file (wrote in gherkin syntax) with two scenarios.

createjap.feature

```
Feature: Create a job application
    
    Scenario: Schedule an employee from jobs table
    Given I navigate to jobs table
    And I select a job
    When I schedule an employee
    Then I should see the employee scheduled in that job

    Scenario: Schedule an employee from planner
    Given I navigate to planner page
```

I use the following script command to run those scenarios:

```
npx cypress-repeat run -n 3 --until-passes
```

Which runs the createjap.feature file three times until all the tests pass. I figured out that if a test fails and the other passes, the one that passed the test runs again. As the project grows this could be impact considerably in the execution time of the tests.

Are there any arguments to run only the failed tests?

Answer (score -1):

Just add `--only-failed`:

```
npx cypress-repeat run -n 3 --until-passes --only-failed
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The output is:

error: unknown option: --only-failed